# How to do multiple validation with formvalidation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I am using [formvalidation plugin](http://formvalidation.io/). I am using [lessThan](http://formvalidation.io/validators/lessThan/) validator. I know validating it like

```
myVar: {
    validators: {
        lessThan: {
            value: check1,
            message: 'Please enter a value less than or equal to %s'
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is I want to validate myVar with 2 values **check1** & **check2**. I tried

```
myVar: {
    validators: {
        lessThan: {
            value: check1,
            message: 'Please enter a value less than or equal to %s'
        },
        lessThan: {
            value: check2,
            message: 'Please enter a value less than or equal to %s'
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives error when using **strict mode**.

How I can achieve ***lessThan*** validation with 2 variables

Comment: In the second part of your code you have duplicate key `lessThan` in an object. that's a syntax error

Comment: @rhgb I know in ***strict mode*** it will give syntax error. My Question is how to achieve ***lessThan*** validation for 2 variables

Comment: I didn't understand you question. You have an element, and you want to validate it to check whether it's less than two values..? What..? for eg, you want to make sure value is less than `10` and also less than `20`..? that doesn't even make sense. Please explain further.

Comment: @TJ I have 2 level validation, 1st is user level and 2nd is role level, now it should validate from both

Comment: @AmitMourya user level and role  level validation applies to same element..?

Comment: @TJ yes it applies to same.

Comment: @AmitMourya So, you have one element with one value, you want to make sure it's less than user level and role level its like `value < 10 && value <20` . if `value < 10` obviously it'll be less than 20 as well. So can't you just validate for the smallest out of your 2 variables?

Comment: @TJ as i told values come from user level and role level. both come from different place and depending on level the error msg will be different

Comment: @AmitMourya use the alias option, see http://formvalidation.io/news/

Comment: @Arkni can you please give an example for my problem, actually i am new to this library

Comment: @AmitMourya Just wondering after reading the comments above, does the role level > the user level ? If no, it doesn't make sense to use the alias option in order to use the `lessThan` validator twice, because the first validator will always fail when you enter a value greater than `check1`. So I suggest you to use the [`callback`](http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/) validator and use your custom logic to validate the field